# Can we simplify $ A^{-1}Bx = x$ where $A$ is a block matrix with each block being diagonal and half the blocks of $B$ are zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, block-matrices

I have the following eigenvalue problem involving block matrices $A$ and $B$:
$$
A^{-1}Bx = x. \quad \quad \quad \quad (*)
$$
$A$ and $B$ have special structures. I would like to reduce/simplify this system to a nicer/alternative form.

1. Structure of $A$:
   $$
   A =
   \begin{bmatrix}
   A_{11} & A_{12} \\
   A_{21} & A_{22}
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
   where each block $A_{ij}$ is a **diagonal** matrix.
2. Structure of $B$:
   $$
   B =
   \begin{bmatrix}
   B_{11} & 0 \\
   B_{21} & 0
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$

**Initial thoughts**: As the blocks of $A$ are diagonal, and hence simple to invert, it would be great if we could somehow rearrange the system so that instead of $A^{-1}Bx = x$ we have something like $\hat A^{-1} \hat B x = x$ with
$$
\hat A =
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & A_{12} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & A_{21} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & A_{22}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
**Questions**:

- Can we re-arrange the system as proposed above? What would $\hat B$ need to be so that the new system corresponds exactly to the original one $(*)$?
- Are there other was of exploiting the structures of $A$ and $B$ such that we can get nice or alternative representations for the problem $(*)$?

Extra note: I am actually dealing with a non-linear eigenvalue problem: Finding $\omega$ such that $\bigg(I - A(\omega)^{-1}B(\omega)\bigg)x = 0$ has a non-trivial solution. My main concern at the moment is somehow exploiting the structures of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: So each block $A_{ij}$ is assumed to have the same dimension? (Consequence of assuming $A_{12}$ diagonal.) And the matrix $A$ necessarily has an even number of rows and columns?

Comment: @Bertrand Yes each $A_ij$ has the same dimension so the full matrix $A$ does have an even number of rows and columns.

Comment: OK, yes in this case, the matrix $A^{-1}$ is block-diagonal as a result of matrix block-inversion. So $A^{-1}$ inherits the same structure as $A$.

Comment: With a permutation similarity, you can make $A$ block-diagonal with $2 \times 2$ blocks on the diagonal

Comment: I don't understand. $A$ is already easily invertible, so how does having $\hat{A}$ helps?  $A$ can be permuted to _almost_ diagonal matrix, i.e. matrix with $dim(A_{12})$ block diagonals of size 2x2.

Answer (score 0):

$\bigg(I - A(\omega)^{-1}B(\omega)\bigg)x = 0 \implies (A(\omega)-B(\omega) )x=0$

so $A(\omega)-B(\omega)$ has 0 as an eigenvalue; so find an $\omega$ such that $det(A(\omega)-B(\omega))=0$

Now you can use $det  \begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\ 
C & D
\end{pmatrix}   =  det\left ( A -BD^{-1}C \right )det(D)$

Comment: I had already considered the determinant formula for block matrices but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere, i.e. it doesn't give us an opportunity to exploit the structure of $A$ and $B$.